# Need for acceleration in particle-antiparticle annihilation?

Tags: collision, antimatter, coulombs-law

If an electron and positron are accelerated towards each other, at distances quite far away, there wouldn't be any significant electrostatic attraction, hence they need to be accelerated. But when they do come close, the Coulomb force is significant. So why do we accelerate the particle antiparticle pair, when they get attracted by electromagnetic forces? What is the need for getting them to collide at high speeds? Doesn't annihilation occur when an electron comes in the field of the positron?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: yes of course they will attract one another through electrostatic attraction: are you seeking confirmation, or do you want to know something else about the attraction?

Comment: I would like to know how the dynamics of the motion would change when the attraction becomes important as the particles collide(due to the momentum imparted not due to the attraction)

Comment: It still isn't clear what you're asking. Until the two particles get within about a Compton wavelength they just behave like any two particles in an inverse square potential.

Comment: I have tried explaining, hope its clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pairs of charged particles and/or objects attract via the $Q_1Q_2/R^2$ Coulomb's law. This is a classical approximation that quantifies how their velocities are changing when the objects are large or distances are much longer than the Compton wavelength etc.

When the particles get really close, there are new effects that are neglected by the laws of classical physics such as Coulomb's law. They must be calculated using the so-called quantum mechanics - or, when the velocities are high or creation/annihilation takes place, quantum field theory is enough.

Quantum field theory implies that the repulsion or attraction isn't the only thing that the electron-positron pair may do. One of the charged particles may also emit a photon and go off-shell for a while, before it emits another photon and goes to the negative, opposite energy-momentum than its partner particles. Then they may annihilate. This is only possible due to the Heisenberg uncertainty – and may borrow an energy for a while.

That's why the particles may annihilate even though their classical trajectories wouldn't even hit each other. In quantum mechanics, the electron and positron trajectory merge into a single trajectory that is bended backwards in time (positron is an electron going backwards in time) and from which two photons are emitted. Such histories have to be summed over and they contribute to processes that are possible. In QFT, creation and annihilation is unavoidably possible as long as charge conservations are respected.

Comment: Does QFT include coulombic effects of the classical nature?

Comment: Sure, one may derive Coulomb's law from QFT between any two charged objects. But Coulomb's law isn't a complete description of all interactions according to QFT.

Comment: What's with the Compton wavelength and inter particle distance?

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be a question constructed so that a part of my text above is the exact answer to it.

Comment: My question has been re edited. I'm asking why do we need to collide them with high velocities for annihilation When all you need is to get them close enough to attract each other and annihilate.

Comment: Sorry, attraction of two objects doesn't mean that they are guaranteed to meet one another. Attraction means that the acceleration is in the direction of their separation - and with the usual $1/R^2$ force law, the two objects move along a hyperbola or an elipse (or a parabola, the marginal case). Unless you infinitely accurately fine-tune the initial velocities, the particles will *not* ever meet. The annihilation only takes place because of effects going beyond the simple attraction and these new effects only begin when they're close to each other which requires a high energy.

Comment: I seem to understand, but your comments makes me think that there are other( presumably non attractive) forces between antiparticles. Please help me.

Comment: The annihilation itself is an interaction that differs from the usual attraction, and there are many others. You are apparently thinking about all these things in terms of 17th century classical physics but 17th century classical physics contains no atoms, no antiparticles, and no annihilation, among tons of other defects. The right (minimal) language to think about particle physics is quantum field theory.

Comment: Thank you. Classical mechanics is too convincing and comfortable for the mind, Mon Cher.